# Android Gradle dependency exclude

Tags: java, android, gradle

One another question about `dependency` duplication/excluding in gradle.
My problem looks like that:

**Dependencies tree:**

- TesterApp

  - DataServices

    - FirstWebService

      - MyJava.Common.Classes
  - MyAndroidGraphics

    - MyAndroid.Common.Classes

      - MyJava.Common.Classes
  - MyUiViews

    - MyAndroid.Common.Classes

      - MyJava.Common.Classes

**Project Tester App**
build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile(project(':data.services'))
  compile(project(':my.android.graphics'))
  compile(project(':my.ui.views'))
}
```

**Data.Services** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile(project(':first.webservice'))
}
```

**My Android Graphics** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile(project(':my.android.common.classes'))
}
```

**My UI Views** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.5'
  compile(project(':my.android.common.classes'))
}
```

**My Android Common Classes** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
  compile(project(':my.java.common.classes'))
}
```

**My Java Common Classes** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.9'
}
```

As you can see, duplicates are with `my.java.common.classes` and `my.android.common.classes`, I cannot merge it as those libraries are used in different projects and are generally common for different projects.

I was trying to use `exclude` like that

```
dependencies {
  compile(project(':data.services')){
    exclude module : ':my.java.common.classes'
  }
  compile(project(':my.android.graphics')){
    exclude module : ':my.java.common.classes'
  }
  compile(project(':my.java.common.classes'))
}
```

Unfortunately doesn't help much, still has

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK trust_root.bks

 File1: D:\projects\android\my.tester.app\my.java.common.classes\build\libs\my.java.common.classes-1.0.jar
 File2: D:\projects\android\my.tester.app\my.android.common.classes\build\libs\my.android.common.classes-1.2.jar
```

Any ideas, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'trust_root.bks' // add this
    }
}
```

Comment: I was testing it with `pickFirst '**/*my.java.common.classes*'` and it's not working, your solution doesn't work too

Comment: Post path to file `trust_root.bks`

Comment: What path it should be? `D:\projects\android\my.tester.app\my.java.common.classes\build\libs\my.java.common.classes-1.0.jar\trust_root.bks`

Comment: @J.D.1731 I've updated answer for your path. Did you try with this path?